# Make this jQuery slideshow crossfade

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a slideshow in my home section, here it is:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var count = 0;
  //replace these images with external ones to test
  var images = ["http://anamarcela.info/imgs/bg2.jpg",
                "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_N_mOB63qPaE/TTSdf7e6YAI/AAAAAAAARsU/YuG9YakI-VI/s1600/3d-wallpaper-Nature.jpg",
                "http://m.jinjianginns.com/images/1.png",
                "http://onepage.owenforsyth.com/1page/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bg3.jpg"];
  var image = $(".fader");

  image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");

  setInterval(function(){
    image.fadeOut(500, function(){
      image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");
      image.fadeIn(500);
    });
    if(count == images.length)
    {
      count = 0;
    }
  },4000);

});
```

```css
.fader {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index: -99;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.home {
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
    padding: 9em 0 41em 0;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--- Home --->
    <div class="container-fluid home" id="home">
      <section class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1">
          <h1 class="main">urbanphenomena</h1>
          <h1 class="sub-main">design+research</h1>
        </div>
      </section>
         <div class="fader">
        
        </div>
        </div>
```

I want the images to crossfade, but it FadesIn and out, and that flashing between the fades is annoying. How can I make it crossfade?

Do you think the .animate() JQuery does it?

Thank you!

Comment: would you be able to modify the code so that I am able to run the snippet?

Comment: To apply such an effect you'll need at least 2 "image" elements, the one which fades has to be "on top" (z-index) of the other one.

Comment: To crossfade using `animate()`, add `queue:false` in the settings object

Comment: @Vivick, may you tell me how to do that, please?

Comment: for instance, for the image that fades out, `$(/*selector*/).animate({/*css properties to animate*/}, {queue: false, /*other settings*/} )`

Comment: Your html structure and your logic will not allow you to crossfade both images... because both images are loaded in the same div one after the other. You possibly need two image elements as @axel.michel has specified